# DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, django-timezone

I have model with **DateTimeField** column.

I'm try to insert row with database **current_time** value directly into table by sql query.

My sql query for MySQL database like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (..., my_datetime, ...) VALUES (..., current_time, ...)
```

And get:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField ModelName.field_name received a naive
>   datetime (2014-01-09 22:16:23) while time zone support is active.

How to insert current time directly into table by sql query without warning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Comment: Good as an alternative [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness `now()` work well for me without warning. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrei Good to hear :) I don't know much about Django, but figured pure SQL should work in there.

Answer (score 42):

Further to falsetru's answer, if the datetime has already been created you can convert it to timezone aware:

```
from django.utils import timezone
my_datetime = timezone.make_aware(my_datetime, timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

Comment: I couldn't find a timezone aware alternative to datetime.datetime.combine() (to create ranges to filter DateTimeFields by date only) and this worked great

Answer (score 24):

Use [`django.utils.timezone.now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) instead of [`datetime.datetime.now`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

```
from django.utils import timezone
current_time = timezone.now()
```

Comment: I need to do sql query directly in database. Not in django.

Comment: @Andrei: I don't think you do. The warning is coming from django, not the database. If you create `my_datetime` using the method described by falsetru the warning won't be generated

Comment: @hellsgate I know that this warning is coming from django, not from database. But my goal is insert row using sql query, not create new object using django model with default field `django.utils.timezone.now`.

Comment: @Andrei: Fair enough. This is still a good answer for you though as ensuring that current_time is tz aware will prevent that warning when you are building your SQL query

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the datetime time zone aware with `localize` from `pytz`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/5802289).

UTC:

```
import pytz
dt_aware = pytz.utc.localize(dt_naive)
```

Any other time zone:

```
import pytz
tz = 'Europe/Berlin' #or whaterver timezone you want
dt_aware = pytz.timezone(tz).localize(dt_naive)
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13866926/5802289) the list of timezones.