# Django - all objects from last hour

Tags: python, django

I would like to get all objects from last hour. For example: I have 13:58 and i would like to get all objects from 13 to 14

This is my code:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
earlier = now - datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, 0,0)
MyModel.objects.filter(date__range=(earlier, now))
```

but I have an error:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField MyModel.date received a naive datetime
>   (2018-02-14 17:16:58.478000) while time zone support is active.
>   RuntimeWarning)

My settings:

```
USE_TZ = True 
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038881/datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare a *naive* date with a time-aware one. When [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) is enabled in `settings.py`, you should use [`django.utils.datetime.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts) over the builtin `datetime.datetime.now()` which is naive when doing comparison or filtering.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from django.utils import timezone

>>> this_hour = timezone.now().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> one_hour_later = this_hour + timedelta(hours=1)
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(date__range=(this_hour, one_hour_later))
```

You can check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) to find out more about how Django handles date times.

Comment: That's the approach, but I think he  wants the range from the beginning of the hour?

Comment: earlier = now - timedelta(hours=1), when i have 13:58, earlier will be 12:58, but  I want 13